# Should I use Task.Wait()?

Tags: task, console-application, wait, c#-2.0

Should I use `taskThatReturns.Wait()` in code below or I can omit it since according to my understanding `taskThatReturns.Result` will do wait anyway.

```
Task<string> taskThatReturns = new Task<string>(MethodThatReturns);
taskThatReturns.Start();
taskThatReturns.Wait();
Console.WriteLine(taskThatReturns.Result);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Task.Start` at all. You should use `var result=await Task.Run(MethodThatReturns);`. There's seldom any valid reason to create a cold task

Comment: Why do you think you *should* be calling `Wait`?

Comment: I have seen `Wait` method on trainings

Comment: KISS is advisable: Console.WriteLine(MethodThatReturns());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call of `Wait()` before accessing `Result` is unnecessary.

Examination of the reference code of [`Task`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs) and [`Task<TResult>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs) shows that both the `void Wait()` method and the getter of the `Result` property eventually make their way into the method that does the actual waiting:

```
internal bool InternalWait(int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Both code paths send identical parameter values to `InternalWait` - infinite wait and default cancellation token.

If you call `Wait` before accessing `Result`, the code path inside the getter leading to `InternalWait` would be skipped, because the task is known to be completed. However, the net result would remain the same in both cases.

**Note:** This answer intentionally ignores opportunities to optimize your code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
async void DoTask() {
  string task = await returnString();
  Console.WriteLine(task);
}

Task<string> returnString() {
  // you code here
}
```

You can use async method to await Task execution

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question.  You either need to wait to get the results, or you need to do as  Panagiotis Kanavos suggested, and await a task.  You're overcomplicating threading, a common issue with all the bad examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use `Task` better approach is:

```
var result = taskThatReturns.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```